# Fetch brands id name from brand table if that brand id is present in products table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've two tables: companies and products
Companies

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 36 | BMW |
| 37 | MERCEDES |
| 39 | LG |
| 40 | MI |
| 42 | APPLE |
| 44 | ONE PLUS |
| 45 | GODREJ INTERIO |
| 46 | USHA |
| 47 | NILKAMAL |

Products

| id | brand | cat_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 44 | 11 |
| 5 | 39 | 11 |
| 6 | 40 | 11 |
| 7 | 44 | 11 |
| 10 | 0 | 0 |
| 11 | 0 | 27 |
| 12 | 0 | 21 |
| 13 | 42 | 11 |
| 14 | 0 | 0 |

I need to fetch brand name and brand id from companies table if that brand id available in products table where category id is equal to 11

Output should be like below

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 39 | LG |
| 40 | MI |
| 42 | APPLE |
| 44 | ONE PLUS |

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, b.media_file
FROM wo_products p
LEFT JOIN wo_companies b
    ON p.brand = b.id
WHERE category = 11 AND user_id = 1
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33jGe.png)

I'm getting well result from above query but brand id is repeated multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want an `exists` query, which is phrased very similarly to your question:

```
select c.*
from companies c
where exists (select 1
              from products p
              where p.brand = c.id and p.cat_id = 11
             );
```

Comment: Please check my query.

Answer (score 0):

That's the Solution

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, b.media_file
FROM wo_products p
LEFT JOIN wo_companies b
    ON p.brand = b.id
WHERE category = 11 AND user_id = 1
GROUP BY id ORDER BY `name` ASC;
```

Comment: Where is the difference to the query in your question?

Comment: there is a new group by in the query

Comment: I'm also getting null value so please let me know how do skip it.

Answer (score 0):

Final Solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.id, b.name, b.media_file
FROM wo_products p
LEFT JOIN wo_companies b
    ON p.brand = b.id
WHERE p.category = 11 AND p.user_id = 1 AND p.brand != ''
GROUP BY id ORDER BY `name` ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a slight performance loss you can go with subqueries which are a bit easier to reason about:

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, b.media_file
FROM wo_companies b
WHERE b.id in (
    SELECT p.brand
    FROM wo_products p
    WHERE p.cat_id = 11 AND p.user_id = 1
)
```